# Why is it an error to construct an unassigned temporary instance of a class with a const char* variable when that class has a const char* constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

Why does this code (unassigned temporary variable constructed from a const char* variable):

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const char*) {}
};

int main()
{
    const char* constCharPointerVariable = "StringLiteral";
    A(constCharPointerVariable);
    return 0;
}
```

Give these errors?

```
error C2512: 'A' : no appropriate default constructor available
error C2040: 'constCharPointerVariable' : 'A' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
```

Whereas this code (assigned temporary variable constructed from a const char* variable):

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const char*) {}
};

int main()
{
    const char* constCharPointerVariable = "StringLiteral";
    A a(constCharPointerVariable);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives no errors.

And this code (unassigned temporary variable constructed from a const char* variable static_cast to a const char*):

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const char*) {}
};

int main()
{
    const char* constCharPointerVariable = "StringLiteral";
    A(static_cast<const char*>(constCharPointerVariable));
    return 0;
}
```

Gives no errors.

Bonus points if you can provide the section number in the C++ specification that specifies the first code sample to be not allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
A(constCharPointerVariable);
```

This is actually a declaration of a variable of type `A` named `constCharPointerVariable`.  It does not create a temporary object.

If you used clang, you'd get the more helpful error message:

```
error: redefinition of 'constCharPointerVariable' with a different type
    A(constCharPointerVariable);
      ^
```

As a simpler example, the following is invalid because it declares two `int` objects in the same scope, both named `x`:

```
int x(0);
int (x);
```

As for why the code is parsed this way, you can find the syntax rules for Declarators in 
§A.7 of C++11.  Basically, when you declare a variable, you can enclose its name in any number of parentheses.

Relevant productions include:

- *declarator* -> *ptr-declarator*
- *ptr-declarator* -> *noptr-declarator* | *declarator-id*
- *noptr-declarator* -> `(` *ptr-declarator* `)`

Comment: +1 - how does anyone remember all this stuff...?  Note that parens around the whole thing will turn it into an expression, making it OK. I guess it's a good thing that we don't often want expressions that are nothing but a single temporary object (though I could see a possible, if still unlikely, use for it with an RAII class).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: It would in any event be terrible class design. If you want something that just does something once, you should probably make it a *function* instead.

Comment: Thanks James, I wasn't aware of that syntax. Your answer is the second time I've heard about clang's well-worded error messages. The first time was from this talk at Microsoft: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Clang-Defending-C-from-Murphy-s-Million-Monkeys

Comment: @NeilJustice:  It's a great tool, and Chandler's presentation is excellent (I attended the Going Native 2012 conference).  I should note that Visual C++ and EDG both emit very similar and equally helpful errors.

Comment: @MichaelBurr:  I had to compile the code to figure out what was wrong :-P. I could never remember all this stuff.